# Create a log to record users who open file as Read-Write

Tags: vba, excel

My team has several files that are designed for other associates to record work in, but not save the file itself. Is there a way to create a version of a user log or change log that records when somebody opens the file read-write or enters the password for the file? The files are password protected, but it seems like someone is able to access them that's not supposed to have that PW.

I can easily create the code to record the username and time once the macro recognizes that the file is opening; I'm just not sure how to tell, if even possible, when it's opened read-write or the read-write password is entered.

Comment: If the file's opened in read-only mode, how would your code record the username?  *Anything* you successfully log in the file itself would imply that the file is writeable by the process that opens it.

Answer (score 2):

```
If Not ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then...
```

write the user name to a text file

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that was perfect!

For some reason, on one file, ThisWokbook.ReadyOnly returned a "automation error; catastrophic error"; however, I changed it to ActiveWorkbook and it worked smoothly.